# How to create custom taghelper in donet core 2.1

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-2.1

I am creating an MVC application on dot net core2.1. I was trying to create a html and ajax taghelper for razor.i was create image actionlink.i have already done this before on .net MVC 5 using extension method but in dot net core I am not able to understand. Can anyone help on this to achieve the same as I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly , I suggest you should take a look at [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on how to create a `TagHelper` . If you still get confused , don't worry and I'll show you a easier explaination .

A `TagHelper` is no more than a piece of server-side code that helps to render HTML elements in Razor . What makes `TagHelper` more powerful is that we can inject configurations and services into it .

Let's take an image as an example . Suppose we want a magic `<magic-image>`, which will be rendered as

```
<img src="localserver-url" />
```

when developing , and will be rendered as

```
<img src="cdn-url" />
```

in production environment .Here the input is `src` , the output is a `<img src=''>` .

There're only 4 rules you need to remember :

1. We can use `[HtmlTargetElement("magic-image")]` to tell the compiler that it will be used as `<magic-image >`
2. We can define as many as our own properties to receive user input . For example , we use `Src` here to hold relative url from user : `<magic-image src='xxx'>`
3. We can use DI with `TagHelper` . In other words , we can have services and configurations/options injected .
4. The `Process()` method is used to map the input to final output . We can set the output.TagName , innerHtml , just as the way we manipulate the DOM with javascript in old days .

Since we need calculate the final `src` according to current environment , Let's create a `TagHelper` with a `Configuration` injected:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("magic-image")]
public class MagicImageTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration{ get; set; } 
    public MagicImageTagHelper(IConfiguration configuration) {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // the `Src` here will be set by user in this way : `<magic-image src="xxxx">`
    public string Src { get; set; }

    // how to map the `<magic-image src="xxx">` to the final output
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "img";    // the element will be <img>

        // ...
        // get cdn base url string from configration , 
        var CdnUrlBase = Configuration["CdnUrl"];

        var src=CdnUrlBase + Src; 

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("src", src);   // set the `img.src`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and showing direction.I started looking into the official document and update with an example soon.